# Help with this correspondence in Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand this question in [Fulton's book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) (page 110):

[image]

I couldn't prove $div(\sum \lambda_if_i)+D\mapsto (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{r+1})$ is indeed a correspondence. I only could prove for the simplest case.

Any help is welcome

Thanks

**EDIT**

The simplest case I mentioned:

If $V$ has dimension one with basis $B=\{f\}$, then

$div(\lambda_1f)+D=div(\lambda_2f)+D\Leftrightarrow div(\lambda_1f)=div(\lambda_2f)\Leftrightarrow \lambda_1f=\lambda(\lambda_2f)\Leftrightarrow \lambda_1=\lambda\lambda_2$

Therefore, the correspondence is well-defined and 1-1. The surjectivity is obvious. Thus this correspondence is a bijection.

Comment: How are you understanding the word "correspondence" here, and what exactly do you mean by "the simplest case"? Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: @JohnBrevik see my edit, please.

Comment: OK. When do two rational functions have the same divisor? What does that say about two elements of $V$ giving the same divisor?

Comment: @JohnBrevik For the first question: $div(f_1)=div(f_2)$ iff $f_1=\lambda f_2$

Comment: @JohnBrevik I don't know the answer for the second question.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm glad we're having this discussion. Elements of V are rational functions, yes? So write out two of these sums and suppose that they give the same divisor. (You're going to use the fact that the $f_j$ form a basis.)

Comment: @JohnBrevik I think I got it! the linear combination of rational functions are rational functions, so I can apply almost the same argument as the "simplest case" I mentioned.

Comment: That's it exactly :)

Comment: @JohnBrevik thank you!